# To install Busybox in OSX

Tags: homebrew, filesystem, unix

I am thinking initramfs -filesystem in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4698/16920).
I run unsuccessfully `brew search busybox` and no including package in Google clearly. 
Busybox is included in Linux by default but not in OSX. 
Different internals so not necessarily possible in OSX.

How can you install busybox in OSX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`initramfs` is something that is very specific to the Linux boot process (it's designed to make the kernel module loading process as flexible as possible) - you won't find an equivalent for OS X.

[BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/), however, is available for Mac OS - see [this Github repository](https://github.com/daliworks/busybox-osx) for example.

That said, I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve as Busybox is simply a set of small utilities that provide core Unix command line functions (`ls`, `cp`, etc). It's commonly used in boot environments and embedded systems due its wide platform support and small size.

Comment: I do a lot of development on macOS but need to run things on BusyBox, so it would be useful to have an easy way to run it directly on my machine.

Comment: Set up a VM and run linux inside the vm.